# Why isn't the case statement case-sensitive when nocasematch is off?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, case-sensitive

Given the following:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.10(1)-release

$ shopt | fgrep case
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off

$ case A in [a-z]) echo TRUE;; esac
TRUE
```

I expect that the capital letter **A** should *not* match the lower-case character class of **[a-z]**, but it does. Why doesn't this match fail?

Comment: `nocaseglob` is unrelated: `If set, bash matches  filenames  in  a  case-insensitive fashion when performing pathname expansion (see Pathname Expansion above)`, though the behavior is still odd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't reliably use the dash this way.  If I don't use dashes, it works as expected:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ case A in [abc]) echo TRUE;; esac
TRUE
$ shopt -u nocasematch
$ case A in [abc]) echo TRUE;; esac
$
```

But *with* dashes, it prints TRUE regardless of the setting of `nocasematch`.

Bash is doing pattern matching here.  Check out [this section of the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) where it says that using the hyphen MIGHT interpret `[a-z]` as `[A-Za-z]`!  It tells you how to get the traditional interpretation (set LC_COLLATE or LC_ALL to C).  Basically your default locale is sorting in dictionary order.  The reference manual explains things pretty well.

**ADDENDUM**

Okay I have a transcript for you.

```
$ shopt -u nocasematch
$ case A in [a-z]) echo TRUE;; esac
TRUE
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ case A in [a-z]) echo TRUE;; esac
TRUE
$ LC_ALL=C
$ shopt -u nocasematch
$ case A in [a-z]) echo TRUE;; esac
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ case A in [a-z]) echo TRUE;; esac
TRUE
```

Answer (score 7):

It has to do with your locale settings. Specifically, the collating sequence is one with case-insensitivity.

For example, with `LC_COLLATE` set to `en_AU.utf8` (the default on my system), you can see that it includes lowercase and uppercase together:

```
pax> case A in [a-b]) echo TRUE;; esac
TRUE
pax> _
```

but, if you get rid of the range specifier, it works as expected:

```
pax> case A in [ab]) echo TRUE;; esac
pax> _
```

That's because the first means `between a and b inclusive` which, for that collating sequence, includes `A`. For the latter means `a` and `b` only, not a range that would be affected by the collating sequence.

If you set your collating sequence to a case-sensitive one, it works as you expect:

```
pax> export LC_COLLATE="C"
pax> case A in [a-b]) echo TRUE;; esac
pax>
```

If you just want to do this as a one-off operation without affecting anything else, you can do it in a sub-shell:

```
( export LC_COLLATE="C" ; case A in [a-b]) echo TRUE;; esac )
```