# In a UNIX/Linux script, how can I check if the user inputs a lowercase letter or uppercase letter?

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

Here is the code that I have so far for the script:

```
# This program displays the character type if given as argument.
#
if [  $# -ne 1 ]
then 
    echo Usage: $0 char             # $0 is program name
    exit 1
fi
# If the user enters more than one character, we will have problems.
# Make sure that the only one character is typed.
#
chars=$1
case $chars in
    [0-9]      )   echo "digit";;
    [a-z]      )   echo "Lowercase letter";;
    [A-Z]      )   echo "Uppercase letter";;
    ?          )   echo "Special character";;
    *          )   echo "Please enter a single character";;
esac
```

I have tried doing different things with the uppercase and lowercase evaluations, but it seems like no matter what I do, when the user enters uppercase it will always evaluate to lowercase=true, or vice-versa. Why is this not working?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695029/why-isnt-the-case-statement-case-sensitive-when-nocasematch-is-off), you can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but there is no need to limit yourself to a single character input. You can easily handle processing a *string* given as the first positional parameter with POSIX compliant shell features and `expr`. While not as fast as bash *string indexes*, you can use `$(expr substr string start length)` to return each character in the string looping with a loop from `1` to `string_length` as `start` with `1` as `length`.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This program displays the character type of each character contained
# in the first argument (positional parameter).

if [ -z "$1" ]
then 
    echo Usage: ${0##*/} string    # ${0##*/} is program name w/o path
    exit 1
fi

string="$1"      ## any number of chars
len=${#string}   ## length of first positional parameter

for ((i = 1; i <= len; i++)); do            ## C-style for, 1 - len
    char=$(expr substr "$string" "$i" "1")  ## get the char at index $i
    case "$char" in
        [0-9]      )   echo "'$char' - digit";;
        [a-z]      )   echo "'$char' - Lowercase letter";;
        [A-Z]      )   echo "'$char' - Uppercase letter";;
        ?          )   echo "'$char' - Special character";;
        *          )   echo "'$char' - Unrecognized character";;
    esac
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh classifychar.sh "My dog has 123 fleas."
'M' - Uppercase letter
'y' - Lowercase letter
' ' - Special character
'd' - Lowercase letter
'o' - Lowercase letter
'g' - Lowercase letter
' ' - Special character
'h' - Lowercase letter
'a' - Lowercase letter
's' - Lowercase letter
' ' - Special character
'1' - digit
'2' - digit
'3' - digit
' ' - Special character
'f' - Lowercase letter
'l' - Lowercase letter
'e' - Lowercase letter
'a' - Lowercase letter
's' - Lowercase letter
'.' - Special character
```

You can adjust what you call a `special` character as desired. If you do not have a C-style loop in your shell, you can use a counter and a `while` loop to accomplish the same thing, e.g.

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$len" ]; do               ## while i=1 - len
    char=$(expr substr "$string" "$i" "1")  ## get the char at index $i
    case "$char" in
        [0-9]      )   echo "'$char' - digit";;
        [a-z]      )   echo "'$char' - Lowercase letter";;
        [A-Z]      )   echo "'$char' - Uppercase letter";;
        ?          )   echo "'$char' - Special character";;
        *          )   echo "'$char' - Unrecognized character";;
    esac
    ((i++))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to make the switch work and evaluate uppercase and lowercase letters.  The link posted by Yi was a similar question, but I tried the suggestions and still couldn't get my script to work.  Installing pax and using it might work, but I had errors on the install, plus it's a big package to install to accomplish this one small task.

Here is what I did:

I replaced these lines:

```
[a-z]      )   echo "Lowercase letter";;
[A-Z]      )   echo "Uppercase letter";;
```

With this:

```
[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]      )   echo "Lowercase letter";;
[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]      )   echo "Uppercase letter";;
```

It might seem a bit silly, it might not be pretty, but hey, it works.

Comment: Your changes do not make any difference. With `case`, `[stuff]` represents a *character class* form of a basic regular expression. The class `[a-z]` is equivalent to `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` (the same logic applies to *upper-case*). If you didn't have to change `[0-9]` to `[0123456789]` what makes you think changing the *lower/upper* case classes made any difference at all? The moral of the story is you can never code by *guess*, *trial and error* or *prayer*. The only way to get it right is to go to the documentation, read until you find the answer, if still no answer, then ask.